# ERC20 token recovery

Tags: erc-20, recovery

I am sorry if this is a stupid question but if someone can help I would appreciate it. first I have the keystore to where the tokens were linked to, I already sync completely to the network. I show the right ethereum balance but my tokens never got recovered. I checked Etherscan to make sure they are still there and they are, but I can't find anyway to recover it in my account. I've looked at tons of forum posts but nothing I can see tells me how to recover tokens in general just the ether itself, can someone please tell me what I need to do? Keep in mind I'm not the best at understanding the ethereum wallet.

Comment: Rest assured, your tokens are there, but the tool you're using presumably doesn't know to show them. ERC20 tokens are just smart contracts deployed to Ethereum, and a tool needs to know about that token contract to display your balance. What tool are you using? Might I suggest https://www.myetherwallet.com (but preferably download the offline version)?

Comment: I tried to use myetherwallet but it keeps freezing and not pulling my keystore?

Comment: I am using I believe the mist wallet

Comment: It can take a few seconds (maybe up to 20 or 30) to decrypt a keystore file... did you wait at least that long? I'm not familiar enough with Mist to know whether it can display arbitrary ERC20 tokens. MetaMask is yet another option.

Comment: I tried it but it just keeps freezing do I need to create an account in myetherwallet to work?

Comment: No, any account should be usable there.

Comment: oK well per the token company they stated that if the tokens don't show they will once there are verification checks verifying the tokens should be in the correct wallet address. Not sure what that means and i'm still pretty stressed over it. I will mess with trying some more with the wallet you gave me and see if I can get it to work. thank you for all the help!

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much. If etherscan.io shows the tokens there for your account, then you have them. It's just a matter of getting the other tools working.

Comment: I actually was able to view the wallet on myetherwallet.com and it is showing the tokens are attached to that address. I just don't know how to get them out if I wanted too?

Comment: Great! You'd just go to https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction, put in the address you're sending to (perhaps an address given to you by an exchange, e.g., if you're going to sell the tokens), and pick the token from the dropdown of what to send.

Comment: Ok well I can see it is in the wallet but I still can't get the keystore to work it just freezes on me but I guess I am a little closer to figuring this out.

Comment: How long have you waited when it "freezes?" Like I said, it can take quite a while to decrypt the private key. It's worth just leaving the page open to see if it eventually completes.

Comment: A really long time, long enough time to go thru 3 times of this application is not responding do you want to wait error windows that come up

Comment: and then it just sits there. maybe I can pull it a different way

Comment: Thank you I was able to fix my issue with your help, the pausing I didn't realize was saying my pass word was wrong. I fix it got the tokens. Thank you sooo much you really helped me on this one!

Comment: I'm glad you got things working!

Answer (score -4):

Unfortunately, your best bet may be to forget about your lost tokens and start investing your time in cryptocurrency technology that is less buggy than Ethereum. I personally don't understand how it has gotten to be worth as much as it has with so many bugs and problems.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about the bugs you mention? Which bugs specifically do you think have affected the OP?

Comment: 1) Syncing problems caused by CryptoKitties

Comment: If by syncing you mean _sending transactions_: The gas price market is working as expected. As demand for block space grows, so does the gas price. People unwilling to increase their gas price will see slower transactions. This is compounded by some wallets/exchanges not auto-adjusting prices, meaning transactions are submitted at prices which are too low. (I'll concede that their are scaling limitations at present. These are being addressed. Anyone can listen to/watch the weekly core dev meeting to understand where various parts of the project are currently at.)

Comment: If by syncing you mean _running a full node_: There's no real need to run a full node if you're not mining or doing something else involved, like developing, etc. That said, syncing a full node, with the correct gear (e.g. SSD not HDD) should only take ~25 hours. See this Reddit thread from last week: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/7n4v64/correcting_rbitcoins_misinformation_i_just_fully/

Comment: No by sync I mean I opened the wallet add the keystore to the appdata folder and it has uploaded/sync all blocks.

Comment: Understood. Your issue is likely what @smarx is suggesting.